# how to add a quick launch webpart in sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

[image]

HI Guys,

I need to add a quick launch web part into my sharepoint site. Please can some one throw some pointers on how can i do it like shown in the attached image

sharepoint 2010

Thanks

Comment: No its just a screen shot given to me. just an image. I need to create a web part like this

Comment: do you mean to say launch client word, excel apps from your web page what if these apps are not installed in client machine or you talikng about office web apps

Comment: i can confirm these will be installed on client machine

Answer (score 2):

You can create a webpart which uses javascript activexobject to launch client apps i'm writing sample for word you can use the same for other applications

```
var pause = 0;
var wdDialogFileOpen = 80;
var wdApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
var dialog = wdApp.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen);
var button = dialog.Show(pause);
```